# Detecting touches in superview of UITableView when it would bounce if bounces weren't = NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I've got a UITableView in a UIView subclass in a UIView subclass.  I want, instead of the cells "bouncing" down when the the top of the table view is dragged down, the whole UITableView and its containing UIView to be dragged down.

I use the following to stop it from "bouncing" at the top of the UITableView.

```
-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        tableView.bounces = NO;
    }
}

-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    tableView.bounces = YES;
}
```

I thought then it might pass touch events for downward swipes up the responder hierarchy.  Alas, no.  How can I best capture the touch events in my superview, which then moves the UIView containing the UITableView down?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, here's an example of similar functionality in an existing app: In Twitter's iPad app, if you are zoomed in the browser, with the left edge of the page touching the left edge of the UIWebView, then if you drag from left to right over the web view you end up dragging the web view. That's pretty much what I'm going for, just vertically and with a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are trying to implements scrolling of an entire view that contains a table.  If that's the case, may I suggest adding the other portions of the view either as cells in the table, or as a subview in the table.

Comment: Okay an example of kindof what I want occurred to me.  In Twitter's iPad app, if you are zoomed in the browser, with the left edge of the page touching the left edge of the UIWebView, then if you drag from left to right over the web view you end up dragging the web view.  That's pretty much what I'm going for, just vertically and with a UITableView.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you have large views, you may run into trouble. TableViewCells max out at 2009 points high.